# Lock address bar to prevent change manually

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, crm

I have an ASP.NET Core project. We have a CRM that if a task stay in your profile for many time than your profile locked so that all of side links will be disabled. Here's my problem that the user can change url in address bar manually and go to another pages. How can I prevent changing the url manually when profile is locked?

Comment: You can't. You can hit a URL using any tool... curl, powershell... any browser.... a different computer... anything. You have to lock it from the back end. You need to recognise in your controllers that the URL is locked and return a 401 or something.

Comment: Thank you very much.can you tell me that how i disable a controller by all actions?

Comment: You add some logic inside the controller that knows when it should be disabled and acts accordingly. How does it know "stay in your profile for many time"? What authentication are you using? You could check the last login time and work off that.

Comment: i use identity authentication.profile Locked until the user to do the task

Comment: Do you know what controller is?